# I'm not sure why this JQuery String isn't working

Tags: jquery, if-statement, statements

I'm trying to do this:

"If the reference in the div with the class 'cart_ref' is equal to 'MAG04WH30' then hide up and down arrows with class names 'cart_quantity_up', 'cart_quantity_down' and disable div with the class name 'cart_quantity_input'. Otherwise show it"

with this line of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var refCodes = $('.cart_ref').text;


if (refCodes = 'MAG04WH30') {
  $('.cart_quantity_up').hide();
  $('.cart_quantity_down').hide();
  $('.cart_quantity_input').prop('disabled','disabled');
}
else{
  $('.cart_quantity_up').show();
  $('.cart_quantity_down').show();
  $('.cart_quantity_input').prop('available','available');
}
});
```

Could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`text` is a method. You should call it using invocation operator `()`. Also for comparison you should use the `==` or `===` operator.

```
var refCodes = $('.cart_ref').text();

if (refCodes === 'MAG04WH30') {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for that. I'm a novice when it comes to JQuery, I've amened the code and it still isn't working. Any ideas?